# What does this C function signature actually mean?

Tags: c, integer, void

What does this type signature mean? I can't wrap my head around it

```c
int (*) ( int(*) (int,int*), int * *)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
int (*) ( // a pointer to a function that return int
    int(*) (int,int*), // 1st argument is a function pointer (A)
    int * * // 2nd argument is a pointer to a pointer to int
)
```

(A) is:

```
int(*) ( // a pointer to a function that return int
    int, // 1st argument is int
    int* // 2nd argument is a pointer to int
)
```

Therefore, it means a pointer to a function whose return type is `int` and 1st argument is "a pointer to a function whose return type is `int` and 1st argument is `int` and 2nd argument is a pointer to `int`" and 2nd argument is a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`int (*) ( int(*) (int,int*), int * *)` is a pointer to a function with return type `int` and parameter types `int(*) (int,int*), int * *`

The first parameter type, `int(*) (int,int*)` is a pointer to a function with return type `int` and two parameters of type `int` and pointer to `int`.

The second parameter type, `int * *`, is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`.

So the whole type is a pointer to a function with:

- return type `int`,
- a first parameter of type pointer to a function with return type `int`, a parameter of type `int`, and a parameter of type pointer to `int`, and
- a second parameter of type pointer to pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> what this means

`int (*) ( int(*) (int,int*), int * *)` is a
[pointer to function (pointer to function (int, pointer to int) returning int, pointer to pointer to int) returning int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*p%29%28int+%28*%29%28int%2Cint*%29%2C+int+**%29)